# flush during runtime:

Tags: php, runtime, flush

I've got a php script running constantly, during which I'm looking at a webpage with the logs. Is there any way to automatically scroll to the last entry when flushing?

My flush function (only way I could make it work):

```
function flush2 (){
    echo(str_repeat(' ',256));
    if (ob_get_length()){
        @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        @ob_end_flush();
    }
    @ob_start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with "scroll" you mean "scroll the browser viewport", this is client-side stuff.

I strongly suggest you to use AJAX to periodically poll a PHP script that returns the "new" stuff (I don't know what it is looking at the example), and everytime it gets some new entry, it creates a new DOM element at the bottom of the page, and scrolls the page down.